# javascript/jquery to create a document set

Tags: document-library, javascript, jquery, document-set

i have seen several SOM examples online for programmatically creating a document set, but I would need to accomplish this with javascript/jquery if possible. Is this possible, and if so how is it done (reference)?

Thanks very much for any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that directly.
What you can do is to use the **/_layouts/Upload.aspx** page and use an ajax file uploader.

What I would do:

1. Use an third part ajax file uploaded such as [valums / file-uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader).
2. Find the *ID* of your library (list).

   ```
   var title = 'D';
   var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
   var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(title);
   ctx.load(list);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
     var id = list.get_id().toString();
     // Use id here
   });
   ```
3. Use the found *ID* to tell where to post your files, something like

   ```
   /_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
   ```

And take it from there, if you open that url and include `&IsDlg=1` it should be possible to see how it accepts data.